# Click on indicator to open app window on top

Tags: unity, indicator, 13.10, panel

When I click on indicator icon on panel, for example qbittorrent, clementine,...etc, the app window opens in background so I have to click on Unity launcher icon or use Alt + Tab to get the windows forward.

Is there a way to open app windows on top of other desktop windows right away from panel icon???

Also both right and left buttons open indicator menu... Is there a way that right button opens menu and left button opens the app window...???

Thanks...

Comment: This is the problem in Unity! This is not your problem! Although you can use some other desktop environment like kde, lxde, cinnamon, gnome3 etc which will give you what you want. You can find the more DE : [What different desktop environments and shells are available?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65083/what-different-desktop-environments-and-shells-are-available)

Comment: Is there any workaround or patch...???

Comment: I don't know any!

Comment: Can we submit this issue as a bug to Canonical ?